# Proving that $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty}B_t/t=0$ a.s. without using the law of iterated logarighm.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I want to prove that  $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty}B_t/t=0$ a.s directly, without using the law of iterated logarithm.

I have read a hint that one can use the law of large numbers. If I look at the sequence $B_n/n, n\in \mathbb{N}$ I can write it as
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{B_i-B_{i-1}}{n},$$
this converges to zero by the strong law of large numbers.

So if I write

$$\frac{B_t}{t}=\frac{B_{\lfloor t\rfloor}}{\lfloor t \rfloor}\cdot\frac{\lfloor t \rfloor}{t}+\frac{B_t-B_{\lfloor t \rfloor }}{t},$$

I have that the first term converges a.s. to zero. So I only need to show that

$$\frac{B_t-B_{\lfloor t \rfloor }}{t}$$ converges a.s. to zero. Do you see how to prove this directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show that $\frac{\sup_{s \in [0,1)} \lvert B_{n+s}-B_n\rvert}n$ tends to zero almost surely as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

We have that
$$ \mathbb P\Big(\sup_{s \in [0,1)} \lvert B_{n+s}-B_n\rvert \geq n^{2/3}\Big) = \mathbb P\Big(\sup_{s \in [0,1)} \lvert B_s\rvert \geq n^{2/3}\Big) \leq 2\mathbb P\Big(\sup_{s \in [0,1)} B_s\geq n^{2/3}\Big) = 2\mathbb P\Big(\lvert B_1 \rvert \geq n^{2/3}\Big) \leq \frac{2 \mathbb E\big[B_1^2\big]}{n^{4/3}}.$$

Borel-Cantelli implies that almost surely there is $\bar n = \bar n(\omega)$ such that for any $n\geq \bar n$ it holds that $\sup_{s \in [0,1)} \lvert B_{n+s}-B_n\rvert \leq n^{2/3}$, and thus $$\frac{\sup_{s \in [0,1)} \lvert B_{n+s}-B_n\rvert}n \leq n^{-1/3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you need is the following (general) result: suppose you have a continuous-in-time stochastic processes $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ such that $\mathbb{E}(X_t) = 0$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty} \mathrm{Var}(X_t) = 0$, then $X_t \to 0 $ almost surely.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to prove that? Using your assumptions I am only able to show that if $t_j$ is a sequence that converges to infinity, then we have a subsequence $t_{j_k}$ such that $X_{t_{j_k}}$ converges to zero a.s. But that is a lot weaker than what we need.

Comment: I think this is fairly standard result... so I need to find a reference for that

Comment: I don't think this is true. There are examples of an infite sequence $Y_n$ of random variables, where $E[Y_n]=0$, $V(Y_n)\rightarrow 0$, so the sequence converges to zero in probability, but there are examples where it does not converge a.s. If we define the function $Z_t$ to be $Y_{n+s}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $s \in [0,1)$, $t=n+s$, we have a counterexample.

Comment: @user394334 thank you for pointing this out!